# Ubuntu 18.04.6: Boots properly only with nosplash, otherwise bootloop without login prompt

Tags: boot, 18.04

Recently, after a routine auto-update to Ubuntu 18.04.6 (kernel 5.4.0-125-generic), the default boot is getting stuck in a bootloop never getting to login prompt. Visually, on the boot the default Ubuntu splash screen is shown (dots progress), but then the splash screen flashes suddenly and is shown again (dots progress), then flashes again ... and so infinitely without ever prompting to login. So I need to press the power button to break the bootloop.

The system can be booted properly, by manually changing `splash` to `nosplash` in the GRUB2 boot menu. Also it's possible to boot into recovery mode.

Examining the journal shows that on the bootloop, it seems that the Xorg fails to start and is then trying to restart each time unsuccessfully. Below is an excerpt from the `/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`, showing the first (EE) error:

```
[    14.945] (--) Log file renamed from "/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.pid-1816.log" to "/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log"
[    14.945]
X.Org X Server 1.20.8
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    14.945] Build Operating System: Linux 5.4.0-121-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    14.945] Current Operating System: Linux box 5.4.0-125-generic #141~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 20:15:56 UTC 2022 x86_64
[    14.945] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-125-generic root=UUID=18b08207-3e7f-4106-a123-58417720e98d ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    14.945] Build Date: 06 July 2022  02:40:21PM
[    14.945] xorg-server-hwe-18.04 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2~18.04.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[    14.945] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    14.945]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    14.945] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    14.945] (==) Log file: "/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Sep  9 09:36:16 2022
[    14.945] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    14.946] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    14.946] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    14.946] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    14.946] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    14.946] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[    14.946] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    14.946] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    14.946] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    14.946] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    14.946] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    14.946] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    14.946]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    14.946] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    14.946]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    14.946] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    14.946]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    14.946] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    14.946]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    14.946] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    14.946]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    14.946] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[    14.946] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    14.946] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    14.946] (II) Loader magic: 0x555d931d0020
[    14.946] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    14.946]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    14.946]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[    14.946]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    14.946]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    14.947] (++) using VT number 1

[    14.950] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c6
[    14.951] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    14.951] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 12 paused 1
[    14.951] (EE) Error systemd-logind returned paused fd for drm node
[    14.951] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 226:0

.....
[    15.397] (EE) modeset(0): drmSetMaster failed: Permission denied
[    15.397] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    15.397] (EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0
```

In the `nosplash` boot, the first (EE) error is absent, instead a respective (II) is shown:

```
[    10.079] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-125-generic root=UUID=18b08207-3e7f-4106-a123-58417720e98d ro quiet nosplash vt.handoff=1
....
[    10.091] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 12 paused 0
....
```

This boots into Xorg ($XDG_SESSION_TYPE x11). But equally, with `nosplash` it can successfully log into Wayland too.

Not sure what may be a problem here. `splash` is probably handled by plymouth, but does `nosplash` exclude plymouth altogether to let the boot proceed?

I can force a `nosplash` in GRUB2, but it seems that there's some latent issue somewhere and I'd rather fix that now than face it in inopportune time.

Comment: Sounds like a video problem.  Do you have Nvidia hardware?  Which Nvidia drivers were/are you using?  How did you install them?  This problem is common when the Nvidia proprietary drivers are not present/working. Search this site for many solutions, basically, clean out existing Nvidia packages and reinstall using the standard repos,.

Comment: No Nvidia, just an onboard Intel HD Graphics 3000 (ThinkPad)

Comment: does `sudo systemctl status systemd-logind` tell you anything?

Comment: In normal boot -- all is ok (active, running), but when in boot-loop (it's rather a startx-loop), I simply don't get to login prompt. I can't even open a VT, as the X fails to start.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what exactly caused this issue but the way I managed to get it resolved is by reinstalling `gdm3` and `ubuntu-desktop`

1. Boot into recovery kernel/console
2. Enable Network
3. Open root prompt

```
     apt install --reinstall gdm3
     apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
     restart
```

This retains all of the current settings; only the files in these packages get reinstalled.

NOTE:
In this case, for some reason the bootloop could be prevented by booting the
kernel with a `nosplash` parameter.

In GRUB, press `E (edit)` on the boot choice and modify the `linux load` command, then `Ctrl+X` to save and boot.